# QueryString.Add not adding value to the Request query strings in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am writing a middleware where I want to modify query string values for the current request but I am unable to do that. afaik `QueryString.Add` method should work but it doesn't affect the query string. Here's what I tried.

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IHeaderValue headerValue, IUser user)
{
    var result = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

    if (result.Count != 0)
    {

        headerValue.UserId = this.GetUserIdFromToken(result[0]);

        var request = context.Request;

        if (request.Method == "GET")
        {
            // It should be adding the new query value to the QueryString collection
            // but it doesn't
            request.QueryString.Add("CurrentUserId", headerValue.UserId.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I will really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Look at the return value of `QueryString.Add`

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks a ton canton!!!!! I did this and it works. `request.QueryString = request.QueryString.Add("CurrentUserId", headerValue.UserId.ToString());` Please post this as answer so more people may get help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`QueryString.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.querystring.add?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_QueryString_Add_System_String_System_String_) returns a new `QueryString` containing the given name and value. It doesn't mutate the `QueryString` on which it's called.

So you need to do something like

```
request.QueryString = request.QueryString.Add("A", "B");
```